# How to load a specific line after a lable?

Tags: assembly, label

I am a beginner in assembly and here is the question:

How can I load a specific line after a label to a register?
For example, there is a label that points to a line:

```
[
LABEL1 .FILL X0011
       .FILL X0100
       .FILL X1234
]
```

We know there is the label `LABEL1` and the line with `x1234` is the second line after the labeled line. How can I load `x1234` to a register (such as register1)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will depend on which assembler you are using, and which platform you are coding for.

Are you using LC-3?

If you are, it looks as if you need something like this:

```
LEA R0, LABEL1   # Load the address of LABEL1 into register R0
LDR R1, R0, 2    # Loads the contents at address (R0 + 2 words) into register R1
```

The value in `R1` should be `x1234` at this point.

If you are not using LC-3, let us know what you are using.

Comment: I am so stupid.. I remembered wrongly of the instruction.. Thank you!